# QList: Difference between length() and count() functions?

Tags: qt, qlist

I'm wondering what the difference between the functions `QList::length()` and `QList::count()` really is.

The [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlist.html) say:

#### `int QList::length() const`

> This function is identical to count().

#### `int QList::count(const T & value) const`

> Returns the number of occurrences of value in the list.
>
> This function requires the value type to have an implementation of operator==().

But how can a function without parameters (`length()`) be the same as one with parameters (`count()`)? The description of the `count()`-function makes sense for me.

However, what does the `length()`-function exactly do? Did they mean that it is the same as the `size()`-function of `QList`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`int QList::length() const` is NOT equivalent to `int QList::count(const T & value) const` but to `int QList::count() const` (see the next signature for the count() method).

The right link: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#count-1

In QList class, methods length(), size() and count() (without parameter) are equivalent and will return the same result.

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks! I just followed the html-anchor-link of the `length()`-function and it - of course - links to the first function-signature -.- so I didn't notice that there is another signature...

Comment: This is a common mistake in the whole Qt documentation. Most of the time the link points to qlist.html#count instead of qlist.html#count-2, due to the automatic doc generation process

Answer (score 3):

There are two count methods, one which takes parameters, and one which does not. If you look at the [source](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1:src/corelib/tools/qlist.h#L124), you can see that length(), size(), and count all have the same implementation (`return p.size();`), and `int QList<T>::count(const T &t)` const has another implementation.

Comment: Do you really *know* that these have the same implemenation or are they just "effectively the same" (this is what they say in the documentation). I'm wondering whether there are any differences in their execution time, that's why I'm picky on your words here ;)

Comment: check the given link https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1:src/corelib/tools/qlist.h at lines 124, 267 and 268. These 3 implementations are equals.

Comment: I typed the implementation right into the answer. return p.size(); That's the implementation for all three methods.